# How to print lines using dotnet twain api to epson plqcs22 passbook printer

Tags: c#, .net, epson, twain, twaindotnet

Is there any possibilities to send printlines to the epson passbook printer using twain api. TWAIN API used: https://github.com/twain/twain-cs

Comment: Well, twain is for **reading** and **not** for printing, so your question does not make sense at all. It is like asking, how to paint with your eyes

Comment: i agreed with that, but why twain specification having Imprinter / Endorser. refer this https://github.com/twain/twain-specification/blob/master/versions/2.3/TWAIN-2.3-Spec.pdf @SirRufo